# Trying to Fetching JSON/JSONP data from url and displaying the result onto a html webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

When I enter the url for instance, `"www.example.com"` I get the return:

```
{
    shh: {
        id: 3730672,
        name: "Shh",
        profileIconId: 23,
        summonerLevel: 2,
        revisionDate: 1421646418000
    }
}
```

I am trying to get all this data and displaying it on my website that is HTML. 
I tried researching and even tried the following code,

```
$.getJSON('www.example.com', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

But it just displays nothing. Please help!

Comment: JavaScript cannot make requests to third party domains due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), unless JSONP or CORS are used. In this case it appears they are not. You need to use a server-side proxy to make the request for you.

Comment: thank you for the information, I never knew about the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data callback is not empty you can try this :

```js
{ shh: { id: 3730672, name: "Shh", profileIconId: 23, summonerLevel: 2, revisionDate: 1421646418000 } }



$.getJSON('www.example.com', function(data){ 
  if(data){
    var ssh = data.ssh;
    var ssh_id = ssh.id;
    var ssh_name = ssh.name;
    
    $('.name').html(ssh_name);
    $('.id').html(ssh_id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name"></span> with id:<span class="id"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ZelkiN, It worked perfectly !!! Can't thank you enough, i spend so many hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the breakpoint there and see what data contains? Also you should use **data.d** in alert instead of just **data**

Comment: I'm using sublime to code, so i'm a bit unsure how to put in breakpoints :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').html(data.shh.id);
```

where you want to put your html id use and in response you will write data then write data or if you use result then you will use result